# Is there any defensive element for non-standard voltages on networks?

Tags: networking, router, security, switch

Assume that an attacker join to our network as a good person and we give him a cable that is connected to one of our switches.

Now, If he connect the wires of that cable to a high voltage (60v for example), what happens? Our switch burns and some of our clients will disconnect. (And also may the network cards may burn also!) is this right?

Is there any device to prevents this kind of attacks? maybe a device that connect cables to switches via a electrical fuse?

Comment: why down vote?!

Comment: I downvoted because you are asking for solutions to a problem which doesn't really exist

Comment: what gives you the idea that an attacker would try to do this?...

Comment: @blaine What is the attacker's goal? They want to break a system sometimes! On what ground you say that they will not to try burn our switch?

Comment: Just that the more "practical" virus would be a much more eficiant way to take down your system.

Comment: Although not a usefull attack, it still is (in my opinion) a good and valid question (and a good answer). +1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First thing that will happen - the cable or router will fry itself. As ethernet is under 5 volts (think around 4v for gigabit, 3.5v for 100) they are not rated for high voltages.

Unless you are running power over ethernet, in which case 120v (or 240v) will be fine.

**But this is mostly irrelevant - it's not a useful attack**

Most companies will not bother trying to protect against this, as it is not a high value (or high likelihood) attack. What does the attacker manage to do? Fry a router/switch. Knock out a few clients? A DDoS attack is likely to have a bigger impact, and you don't need to be physically present.

The company will just pop it out, and plonk in a new one and everyone is back up and running. For standard network devices they may have ones in store and ready.

If the attacker tries to go for one of the core routers, your protection is more physical - why would you let them get into your data centre and plug into that router? Access should be strongly controlled there.

Comment: With physical access there are so much more effective ways of destruction, like a hammer.

Comment: Yep - that too :-)